# Select xml node by attribute in php

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

How do I find the node value by knowing the attribute value without traversing through every child and every attribute/value ?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('test.xml');

$rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName('row');

foreach ($rows as $row) {

$header = VALUE OF <field name="header">
$text = VALUE OF <field name="text">

}
```

XML:

```
<resultset>
  <row>
    <field name="item">2424</field>
    <field name="header">blah blah 1</field>
    <field name="text" xsi:nil="true" />
    ...
    </row>

  <row>
    <field name="item">5321</field>
    <field name="header">blah blah 2</field>
    <field name="text">some text</field>
    ...
  </row>
</resultset>
```

Comment: You can't... Even if you use a library, in the back end, it's going to have to traverse the tree to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest thing to do is use [`DOMXPath::query`<sup>*docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

The following code finds all the `<field>` nodes within `<row>` nodes that have a name attribute equal to "header":

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($str); // where $str is a string containing your sample xml
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = "//row/field[@name='header']";

$elements = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($elements as $field) {
  echo $field->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Using the sample xml you provide, the above outputs:

```
blah blah 1
blah blah 2
```

Comment: I had thought about xpath as well but it will only allow me to select one field? I need several variables populated for each "row"

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking but you can just stack up the attribute conditions like so: `$query = "//row/field[@name='header'][@other_attr='anything']";`  If you're asking if you can grab multiple types of elements with a single xpath, then no. You could do multiple xpath queries or loop over all of them. Sorry if that's what you were asking in the first place. *"find the node value by knowing the attribute value"* -- which is what your question says -- is an xpath situation, though.