# getElementByAttribute PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select xml node by attribute in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252928/select-xml-node-by-attribute-in-php)

Is there any function like `getElementByAttribute` in PHP? If no, how do I create a workaround?

E.g.

```
<div class="foo">FOO!</div>
```

How do I match that element?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699821/php-check-if-xml-node-exists-with-attribute

Comment: Not the same, HTML can be trickier than XML if it's not XHTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='foo']");
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/8AL91w0y)