# PHP Get element value by tag variable

Tags: php, domdocument

If I have the following html:

`<div id="thisID">100</div>`

I can get the value, 100, like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$data = $dom->getElementById("thisID");
$result = $data->nodeValue;`
```

But what about this html?

`<span class="foo" id="bar" itemprop="price">100</span>`

Is there a way I can get an element content by a tag variable and value, in this case `itemprop="price"`?

Comment: Use DomXpath - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6827943/1164491

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064741/getelementbyattribute-php-dom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064741/getelementbyattribute-php-dom

Answer (score 0):

a) Use DOMXPath:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<span class="foo" id="bar" itemprop="price">100</span>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$result = $xpath->evaluate('number(//*[@itemprop="price"])');
```

b) Use [a real microdata parser](https://github.com/linclark/MicrodataPHP).